# Equivalents to vim \zs and \ze?

Tags: regular-expressions

In vim, all instances of `an apple tree` can be replaced by `an orange tree` with `:%s/an \zsapple\ze tree/orange/g`.
`\zs` and `\ze` mark the start and end of the passage to be operated on.
Is there something equivalent in emacs?
As far as I know, evil mode needs the much less elegant
`:%s/\(an \)\(apple\)\( tree\)/\1orange\3/g`

Comment: The general answer is that Emacs regular expressions do not support these zero-width assertions. (For specific cases like this you can achieve the same result, as @Jan has shown.)

Comment: Please edit your post to explain what `\ze` and `\zs` are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `M-x query-replace-regexp`and use `apple\( tree\)` as search text and `orange\1` as replacement.

`query-replace-regexp` will search for the first string and will ask you to replace the second string.  You can use the exclamation mark `!` to replace all of them without further questions.